# Adjust my page after the appearance of a div

Tags: jquery

UPDATE :
I created two buttons at the bottom of my web page who must show forms. Unfortunately, the page hide this forms when we click on one of this buttons.

[pepitodanger.free.fr/Maquette/](http://pepitodanger.free.fr/Maquette/)

So I wrote this code but when I click on a button nothing happens.

```
$(".btn-form").on("click", function() {
    $('#page').scrollTop($("#all-forms").offset().top);
    return false;
});
```

How to make the page adjusts itself at the level of the forms ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `#btn-form` should be changed to `.btn-form`
2. `#page` doesn't even exist on your site. change it to `$(document).scrollTop(...`

that would result in the following:

```
$(".btn-form").on("click", function() {
  $(document).scrollTop($("#form-devis").offset().top);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry the correct version of my page was not updated on the server. Now it contains the div #page. I have updated my question.

Comment: still, try to replace #page with document.

Comment: Thank you. It works only when I click twice on one of the buttons

Comment: maybe try to integrate the `$(document).scrollTop($("#form-XYZ").offset().top);` into the already present click handlers on the buttons (the one where you show/hide the forms)